# CLIPS: reference to ruleName

Tags: clips

is there a way to output the name of the fired rule in CLIPS?
Example:

```
     (defrule this-is-my-rule
         ...
         =>
         (printout t "this-is-my-rule: and these are the outputs" crlf) ;;#1 
      )
```

Instead of writing manually the name of the rule in #1, I'd like to use a psecific command (if any).
Is it possible, please?

Thank

Nicola

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a mechanism for programmatically determining the name of the currently executing rule, but you can use the watch debugging command to print the name of each rule as it is executed:

```
CLIPS> (defrule rule-1 =>)
CLIPS> (defrule rule-2 =>)
CLIPS> (defrule rule-3 =>)
CLIPS> (watch rules)
CLIPS> (run)
FIRE    1 rule-3: *
FIRE    2 rule-2: *
FIRE    3 rule-1: *
CLIPS>
```